# How can I get div text from external website

Tags: php

I want to get the div text(school) from url.

```
<div id='listBox'>
    <div class='list'>
        <span class='listID'>01101602</span>school
    </div>
    <div class='department'></div>
    <div class='nop'></div>
</div>
```

I already tried Several ways:

1.`file_get_html` and `query('//div[@class="list"]');`

2.`file_get_contents` with `$first = explode( '<div class="list">',$content );` and `$second = explode("</div>" , $first[0] );`,then `echo $second[0];`

I could't get it to work...

Comment: do you want it in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: Please add your code what you tried so far?  Also did you get any error while trying different solutions? Tell use the url also from where you want to extract this div text

Comment: Show code with that: `file_get_html and query('//div[@class="list"]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's dirty solution, but code that you pasted is not valid XML/HTML, so it can't be parsed by normal XML/HTML parsers.

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("http://page.com/file.htm");
$explode1 = explode('</span>', $text);
$explode2 = explode('</div>', $explode1[1]);
$schoolText = trim($explode2[0]);
```

This part is not valid HTML (missing < to open div):

```
<div class='department'>/div>
```

This text (school) will be ommited by all/almost all HTML parsers:

```
<span class='listID'>01101602</span>school
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem to use domDocument with Xpath

```
$html = "<div id='listBox'>
<div class='list'>
    <span class='listID'>01101602</span>school
    </div>
    <div class='department'>/div>
    <div class='nop'></div>
</div>";

$dom = new domDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new domXpath($dom);
// Get innerHTML of the div
foreach($xpath->query('//div[@class="list"]')->item(0)->childNodes as $x) {
   echo $dom->saveHTML($x);
}
// <span class="listID">01101602</span>school
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to load the remote page directly into a new instance of `DOMDocument` and use an `XPath` query to find the node you want

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
$xp=new DOMXPath($dom);
$query='//*[@id="listBox"]/div[@class="list"]/span[@class="listID"]';
$col=$xp->query($query);
if( !empty( $col ) && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Depending upon the validity of the HTML found at the remote site you may need to use some of the `libxml` error handling methods like

```
/* try to prevent errors */
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
/* clear errors */
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath($dom);
$query='//*[@id="listBox"]/div[@class="list"]/span[@class="listID"]';
$col=$xp->query($query);
if( !empty( $col ) && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: This looks correct, but there is no output or error message.